# SQL Casing Help for Date Time Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am running this query:

```
SELECT
    sm.UPDATE_DATE
FROM
    EAT_Tickets
    LEFT JOIN
        MAS_Users
        ON EAT_Tickets.tic_assignedTo = MAS_Users.use_userKey
    INNER JOIN
        EAT_TicketStatusesLK
        ON EAT_Tickets.tic_ticketStatusKey = EAT_TicketStatusesLK.tis_ticketStatusKey
    INNER JOIN
        [HSHPSQL03].[ServiceManager].dbo.[OCMLM1] sm
        ON sm.NUMBER = EAT_Tickets.tic_oarID
WHERE
        sm.UCD_Status <> 'Closed'
    AND sm.UCD_Status <> 'denied'
    AND sm.NUMBER = EAT_Tickets.tic_oarID
    AND sm.UCD_BRIEF_DESC NOT LIKE '%Access termination%'
    AND MAS_Users.use_ADLogin = 'User1'
```

It obviously returns datetime such as `2015-06-15 06:48:12:000`

However, I want to add some sort of casing because I want to see how many are up-to-date within 3 days. For example, if i have 5 results and 4 of them are within 3 days of today's date, i want the result set to show "4". I dont need to see dates/times. I want the casing to compare the dates within 3 days and add to the count. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it for you. The sum will add up any date within 3 days.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, sm.UPDATE_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 3 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) 'DaysWithin3'
FROM EAT_Tickets
LEFT JOIN MAS_Users
  ON EAT_Tickets.tic_assignedTo = MAS_Users.use_userKey
INNER JOIN EAT_TicketStatusesLK
  ON EAT_Tickets.tic_ticketStatusKey = EAT_TicketStatusesLK.tis_ticketStatusKey
INNER JOIN [HSHPSQL03].[ServiceManager].dbo.[OCMLM1] sm
  ON sm.NUMBER = EAT_Tickets.tic_oarID
WHERE sm.UCD_Status <> 'Closed'
AND sm.UCD_Status <> 'denied'
AND sm.NUMBER = EAT_Tickets.tic_oarID
AND sm.UCD_BRIEF_DESC NOT LIKE '%Access termination%'
AND MAS_Users.use_ADLogin = 'User1'
```

Comment: Pure genius. Thank you so much Holmes.

Comment: @Sushil sorry for getting lazy on my code format, I will be better about!

Comment: thats ok @HolmesIV everybody does that once in a while. you don't need to be sorry for that.